# GCP - observing API hang

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I see the first call to GCP API hang at times - not always.  Below is the stack trace.

I am based on python 2.7, GCP SDK 1.5.5

**Sequence:**

```
http = httplib2.Http()
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    if http:
        gcp = GCP_discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials, httt
p=http)
    else:
        gcp = GCP_discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    list = gcp.routes().list(project = project).execute(http=http)
```

The last call to gcp never returns.  Replacing `gcp.routes().list()` with a different API also causes a hang.  If i restart everything goes through fine.

```
File: "/opt/avi/python/bin/cloud_connector/baremetal/gcp_client.py", line 677, in _reconcile_all_vips
  rtlist = gcp.routes().list(project=xpn_project).execute(http=http)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
  return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 833, in execute
  method=str(self.method), body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 160, in _retry_request
  resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 175, in new_request
  redirections, connection_type)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 282, in request
  connection_type=connection_type)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1609, in request
  (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1351, in _request
  (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1334, in _conn_request
  content = response.read()
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 578, in read
  return self._read_chunked(amt)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 620, in _read_chunked
  line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
  data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 341, in recv
  return self.read(buflen)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 260, in read
  return self._sslobj.read(len)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I see couple of issues in the code snippet you posted:

1. You have a typo `http=http` instead of `htttp=http`
2. If you want to use HTTP2 (using `httplib2.Http`), you should [authorize the http2 instance to use your GCP account credentials](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.client.html#oauth2client.client.Credentials.authorize). This part is missing in your code.
3. If you're passing `http=` argument to [`disccovery.build()`](https://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build), you should not be passing `credentials=` argument any more (related to point 2 above). The 2 arguments are mutually exclusive.
4. You need to pass the `http=` argument to `execute()` only if you are using HTTP2.

Because of the if condition, it is not quite clear if you intend to use with HTTP2 or without. Also, none of the problems I mentioned above seem to be directly related to the problem you're observing, so not entirely sure it's going to fix your issue.

Just for reference, I tried the below code snippet on my GCP project which calls the `list()` API on `routes` 1000 times once without HTTP2 and again with HTTP. I did not notice any hang in my case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import httplib2

# Fill in your project name here
PROJECT_NAME = ''

class GcpComputeApi:
    def __init__(self, use_http2=False):
        credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
        self.use_http2 = use_http2
        if use_http2:
            self.http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
            self.gcp_compute = build('compute', 'v1', http=self.http)
        else:
            self.gcp_compute = build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    def list_routes(self):
        if self.use_http2:
            return self.gcp_compute.routes().list(project = PROJECT_NAME).execute(http=self.http)
        else:
            return self.gcp_compute.routes().list(project = PROJECT_NAME).execute()

compute_api = GcpComputeApi()
for ix in range(1000):
    list = compute_api.list_routes()
    print "ix = " + str(ix) + " len = " + str(len(list))

compute_api_using_http2 = GcpComputeApi(use_http2=True)
for ix in range(1000):
    list = compute_api_using_http2.list_routes()
    print "ix = " + str(ix) + " len = " + str(len(list))
```